# In Laravel 5 error in array validation with Form Request?

Tags: php, html, forms, laravel, laravel-5

The part of form (the field text array)[1]:

```
<div id="cp1">
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::text('names[]',null,['class'=>'form-control', 'maxlength'=>'30', 'placeholder'=>'Name']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::text('contents[]',null,['class'=>'form-control', 'maxlength'=>'30', 'placeholder'=>'Content']) !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

When i send the form, validation fails with:
htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/telovendogdl/resources/views/ads/new.blade.php)

this is the rules in form request:

```
return ['title' => 'required|min:8|max:100',
            'description' => 'required|min:10|max:1100',
            'price' => 'required|integer|max:15',
            'city_name'=> 'required|max:70',
            'category_id' => 'required|integer',
            'delivery'=> 'max:70',
        ];
```

This is the function in the controller:[2]

```
public function newAdStore(StoreNewAdRequest $request)
    {
        $newAd = new Ad;
        $newAd->user_id = \Auth::user()->id;
        $newAd->active = 0;
        $newAd->city_name = $request->input('city_name');
        $newAd->category_id = $request->input('category_id');
        $newAd->fill($request->all());
        $newAd->save();
}
```

but only fails when i send the array fields from the form [1], when a delete this fields all works? what happen with that[2]?

Comment: Can you post the relevant part of your view and the fillable fields defined in your model ?

Comment: I solved adding the index number to the array Form::text (names[]), starting with 0,1,2, etc.. and now Works :)

Comment: Glad you made it. As you could manage to solve it by yourself you can post your answer by explaining the root cause and the solution you took, so the question is valuable for others facing the same issue. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a clear vision of your code but I am gonna try to help you debug your code ... first you need to add a rule to your StoreNewAdRequest to handle an array instead of string for names[] and contents[] :

```
public function rules()
{
  $rules = [
    'field2' => 'required|...',
    'field3' => 'required|...',
     ....

  ];

  foreach($this->request->get('names') as $key => $val)
  {
    $rules['names.'.$key] = 'required|max:100';
  }

  return $rules;
}
```

Make sure you have the right fillable params in your model

**Note:** the problem maybe occurred at this stage

```
$newAd->fill($request->all())
```

you are trying to fill an array of names[] & contents[] instead of strings ..